# Java - loop over multiple arrays (String does not match "array type")

Tags: java, arrays, variables

```
static String[] E1 = {"filex1", "file333y", "readme"};
```

I got five arrays (E1, E2, E3, E4 and E5) that I define like above. In those arrays there are file names. I want to loop over each E* array individually and do sth with the file.

```
String eb = "E"+i;
```

was my attempt to loop over them, but when I call it in the other loop with

```
eb[j]
```

it gives me sth like "eb is a String but array type is needed here"...

```
for( int i = 0; i < ENum - 1; i++)
{
  String eb = "E"+i;
  for( int j = 0; j < eb.length - 1; j++)
  {
    String tempFile = Path4Files+eb[j]+".txt";
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean to use E1[j]?

Comment: What is `ENum` ? Why don"t you store each table in a `List` and iterate through this list ?

Comment: @jeanr ENum defines how much arrays I want to look at. Because that was the solution I didn't know about.. but it works for me now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Andres stated in his answer, the only way is reflection, although only for member variables.

One solution would be adding your arrays to another array and then looping over it.

```
static String[] E1 = {"filex1", "file333y", "readme"};
//...
static String[][] es = {E1, E...};
```

Comment: even if you repeat it with your second account : the question still isnt about reflection.

Comment: Yes, multidimensional arrays are another way of doing it. Please forget about that "reflection" nonsense for now - thats unnecessary and somewhat advanced.

Answer (score 3):

Create one multidimensional array:

```
static String[][] E = {{"filex1", "file333y", "readme"}, {...}, {...}, {...}, {...}};
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Eggs {
    static String[] E1 = {"filex1", "file333y", "readme"};
    static String[] E2 = {"aaa", "bbb", "ccc"};
    static String[] E3 = {"ddd", "eee", "fff"};
    static String[] E4 = {"ggg", "hhh", "iii"};
    static String[] E5 = {"jjj", "kkk", "lll"};
    public static void main(String[] args){
        List<String[]> myList = Arrays.asList(E1,E2,E3,E4,E5);
        for(String[] myArray: myList){
            for(String myString: myArray){
                System.out.println(myString);
            }
        }
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To access a variable in Java by composing its name from pieces of Strings you need to use [reflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(computer_programming)#Java). Also, it will only work for member variables, not for automatic variables.

Comment: this question has nothing to do with reflection nor variable access. At all.

Comment: How do you access a member variable in java if to get its name you have to concat two Strings?

Answer (score 0):

You can do sth like this:

```
String[] E1 = {"filex1", "file333y", "readme"};
String[] E2 = {"filex21"};
for (String[] files : new String[][] {E1, E2})
{
  for(String fileName : files)
  {
    String tempFile = Path4Files + e[j] + ".txt";
  }
}
```